# Scaling with zoom

Tags: inkscape, zoom

Is it possible to set objects to scale in some way as you zoom in and out?  Some objects are challenging to see at extremes of zoom.  For instance, lines can be too thin to see when zoomed way out but become way thick when zoomed in.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but would switching to an outline mode in "View" - "Display Mode" - "Outline" solve your issue?

Comment: So... you want to zoom.. but not have objects change (visual display) scale when zooming? Isn't that a direct contradiction to what *every* zoom function does? And would ultimately make zoom worthless? Why would you need zoom at all if nothing changes display scale?

Comment: @J.E - you're right, not a direct answer, but interesting and useful nonetheless.

Comment: @Scott - if all objects scaled in every way, you're right, zoom would make no difference, but if some objects kept their line thickness it might be visually helpful.

Comment: I guess I still don't understand. I can't imagine how zoom would be helpful if it failed to maintain scale between objects.  I see the *entire point* of a zoom function as the ability to see how objects relate to one another at varying display scales. If I want to align a path to a shape... when I zoom in, if that path does not maintain relative scale to the shape, any changes I make would be haphazard and random. To me, it merely sounds like you should *not* use zoom..

Comment: This, to me, is like wanting a dimmer knob on a standard incandescent lightbulb.. but asking the dimmer to only vary the red spectrum and leave the blue spectrum alone. It's not feasible.

Comment: I have had the same problem, I understand exactly what you mean. For those who don't understand: I recently created a logo  that had both lines and fills in it. When I created the logo I always zoomed in a lot so that I could see what I was doing. When I finished I zoomed out to the original scale and suddenly my lines where extremely thick, which completely changes the look of the logo. To me it always felt as if the line thickness doesn't scale properly with the zoom relative to the rest of the object. It's not about the object, just about the line thickness.

Comment: @Bianca Usually icons are drawn in different *level of detail*s to work around this problem when displaying them. However, each level of detail is drawn by hand and I'm not aware of a tool that would create multiple level of details automatically.

Comment: @socowi I don't understand what you mean. What's a level of detail?

Comment: @Bianca Images with low resolution usually need thicker strokes and less details. Apparently there is a tool to create multiple levels of detail (also known as *multi resolution* icons). https://brandmark.io/logo-crunch/ On the linked site are a few good examples.

Comment: Scale does *not* equal zoom. They are two separate and *different* things. Scale alters an objects size . Zoom merely alters what is *displayed on screen* and does *not* alter objects.  There seems to be a great deal of mingling of the two terms here. The are *never* the same thing. Yes if you *scale* something, you may need to adjust some sizing. But *nothing* should  *ever* need adjusted due to zoom.

Comment: @Scott you're absolutely right. I rechecked my logo,and it seems  I got confused between the two. The problem I was having had nothing to do with zoom. It was only when I scaled the objects that the lines appeared thiner or thicker. This is an optical illusion, the lines simply don't change size. While the object get's bigger with the scale, the stroke weight stays the same. Also I'm working in Illustrator, and I only just noticed Jack is talking about Inkscape. So apologies to everyone if my comments where confusing.

Comment: Illustrator has an option to scale strokes when scaling the object. I don't know enough about Inkscape to say if it has the same thing, but @Socowi 's answer would seem to indicate it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### First of all ...

... I would refrain from using such an option. Changing the stroke width depending on the zoom would most likely trick you into thinking that your image looks different than it actually does.
For working with very thin or thick lines, you can temporarily change to `View` → `Display Mode` → `Outline`.

#### Possible Solution

SVG elements can have the property `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"`, see [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/painting.html#NonScalingStroke). Inkscape respects that property, but you have to add it manually using the xml editor.

1. Select an object.
2. Open the xml editor.
3. Under *style*, change `vector-effect:none` to `vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke`.
4. Press *set*.

[image: xml editor]

#### Example

Here are screenshots of an example image. There are two filled circles with a stroke of width `10px`. Only the blue circle on the right has the property `vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke`.

The following screenshots were made at different zoom levels.
For better comparison of the stroke width I copied small parts of all screenshot and pasted them right next to each other. As we can see, the blue circle keeps its stroke width for all zoom levels.

[image: Scene at different zoom levels]

#### Caveats

- In the example from above both circles have the same stroke width, but at zoom level 100% the yellow circle's stroke is thicker. Seems like a bug in Inkscape. I use version 0.92.2 2405546, 2018-03-11 on Linux.
- You should change `non-scaling-stroke` back to `none` after you are done editing. Not all applications support it.

Comment: That might just work.  My current Inkscape project uses Inkscape as a sort of fractal drawing storage facility, where some moderately detailed drawings are kept quite small, so that you can zoom in and see them, but when you zoom out, you see items on a larger scale.  Hope I've explained that so it makes sense.  I don't ever use "the whole drawing", I use parts of it, screen capped and exported.  So your solution may work very well.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for this brilliantly illustrated answer! I can confirm that the bug you mentioned, about line thickness not being equal at 100% zoom level, is still existing in 2022 (I use Inkscape version 1.0.2)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up at this question for a different reason and want to add my solution in case someone has the same problem.

When exporting a vector graphic as an svg file from a python plot (e.g. created using plotly) and importing this file into inkscape, some of the lines, by default (!), will have the property that the question by user Jack was asking for: lines will change their thickness when zooming such that on screen they always have the same thickness. This was undesired in my case and is illustrated in these figures:

Zoomed-in version:

[image]

Zoomed-out version:

[image]

As you can see, the green line thickness automatically changes with the zoom, such that on screen the line thickness is always the same - not good if you want to know what your figure actually looks like!

As pointed out by user Socowi, one simply needs to edit the `vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke` property of those lines, in my case, removing this option from the lines. In the plots shown above, I removed this property from the lines of the red boxplot and zooming in and out now works as it should.

However, if you don't want to edit this property for all your lines, you can rest assured that when exporting to pdf, line-thickness will again scale with zoom as intended.